# 2014 Honda CRV Air Recycling Light

Tags: honda, crv, climate-control

My recycling air light comes on intermittently. My salesman says that's normal, the car knows when it needs to shut off air from the outside. Mighty smart car, but then it's a Honda. Is he blowing smoke up my kilt?

Comment: +1 for not knowing whether I'd like to experience the *smoke up my kilt* or not. I'd suggest the answer is, your salesperson is spot on and you have nothing to worry about, but maybe someone else has some direct knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Your air re-circulation does not automatically come on.

Your salesperson is ***blowing smoke up your kilt***.

The air re-circulation is controlled manually only.  This would be a warranty item.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from the owner manual for the 2014 CRV

**Controlling the source of air**

The Recirculation Button controls the source of the air going through your climate control system. When in Recirculation Mode, air from the vehicle's interior is recirculated through the system. Use this mode when driving through smoky or dusty conditions, or when you need maximum A/C cooling. Keeping the system in Recirculation Mode, however, especially with the A/C off, can cause the windows to fog.

No mentions of system control of the recirc mode.

There has been talk of forced recirc mode in the engineering circles since it can improve mpg in some situations. This would happen only after the inside temp is lower than the outside when using A/C. CARB has considered mandating this mode, but I do think it has been implemented.